# Replace ignores non-capture group

Tags: regex, vb.net

Why does `Regex.Replace` ignore my non-capturing group? I am removing bracketed numbers that occur at the end of a filename, whether this is followed by 0, 1 or 2 extensions. For example,

> whatever(54).xml

will become

> whatever.xml

This doesn't work:

```
Private Function FixFileName(ByVal fn As String) As String
    Static rgx As New Regex("(\(\d+\))(?:(\.\w{2,3}){0,2})$")
    Return rgx.Replace(fn, "", 1)
End Function
```

it removes extensions after the numbers, even though I'm not capturing them. This works:

```
Private Function FixFileName(ByVal fn As String) As String
    Static rgx As New Regex("(\(\d+\))((\.\w{2,3}){0,2})$")
    Return rgx.Replace(fn, "$2", 1)
End Function
```

by capturing, and then reinserting, the extensions (if any).

Some test code:

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On

Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        RichTextBox1.WordWrap = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
            Handles Button1.Click
        Dim filenames() As String = {"wibble(a).xml", "blah (blah( blah)).xml", "blah(54)",
                                     "blahblah(433).xml", "blah(2)blah(500)", "blah(23)blah(500).xml",
                                     "blah(23)blah(500).xml.doh"}

        For Each filename As String In filenames
            RichTextBox1.AppendText(filename & " --> " & FixFileName(filename) & vbNewLine)
        Next
    End Sub
```

This image might be useful:

[image: regex101]

I want to know whether this is by design or if there is something wrong with my regex? And whether an attempt at a `positive lookahead assertion` might work.

Comment: Are you looking to replace both sets of numbers within the `( )`, (eg. `blah(23)blah(500).xml.doh` would result in `blahblah.xml.doh`?`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, just the last set before any extension(s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regardless of whether you create a capture or not, [`.Replace()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1(v=vs.110).aspx) will always **replace the whole match**. From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1(v=vs.110).aspx):

> **[Regex.Replace Method (String, String)](http://](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1(v=vs.110).aspx))**
>   In a specified input string, replaces all strings that match a 
>   regular expression pattern with a specified replacement string.

---

This is by design, and an expected behaviour in all regex flavours. You are correct, you need to use a group for the *extensions*, and backreference it in the substitution.

An extra comment: there's no need to use a group in `(\(\d+\))`, since you don't need to capture it (or at least not in the example you provided). `\(\d+\)` would work just as fine.

And then again you're right, you could use a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), to assert without consuming characters in the match.

**Regex:** (spoiler)

> `\(\d+\)(?=(?:\.\w{2,3}){0,2}$)`

- <sub>Move your mouse over the above block to see the regex with a lookahead (it wasn't clear in the question whether you wanted the solution or only to know if it would work)</sub>

**Output:**

```
wibble(a).xml --> wibble(a).xml
blah (blah( blah)).xml --> blah (blah( blah)).xml
blah(54) --> blah
blahblah(433).xml --> blahblah.xml
blah(2)blah(500) --> blah(2)blah
blah(23)blah(500).xml --> blah(23)blah.xml
blah(23)blah(500).xml.doh --> blah(23)blah.xml.doh
```

[DEMO](http://rextester.com/NJHBC3915)

Comment: Thank you. I suspected it was by design, just couldn't find a clear statement saying that non-captures would be ignored.

Comment: Indeed, and that's because non-captures are not ignored, as well as captures are not considered. It replaces the whole match, even if you use capturing groups, non-capturing groups or none.

Comment: Thank you. (Captures are considered to the extent that "$2" is used in the replace term.)